# How do you prevent a user from resizing the column width of a clistctrl (report view)?

Tags: list, mfc, visual-c++, resize, column-width

How do you prevent a user from resizing the column width of a clistctrl (report view)?

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to override the`OnNotify` method to catch header's TRACK messages.
Here is a solution: [Prevent column resizing](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/controls/listview/columns/article.php/c1065)

**Update:** on newer MFC versions and on Vista, there is the `LVCFMT_FIXED_WIDTH` format flag.
You can set that flag when you insert the column: see [LVCOLUMN Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774743%28VS.85%29.aspx)

> `LVCFMT_FIXED_WIDTH`
>    Version 6.00 and Windows Vista. Can't resize the column; same as `HDF_FIXEDWIDTH`.