# Prevent resizing first column in ListCtrl (ReportView)

Tags: winapi, mfc, controls

I come from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535353/how-do-you-prevent-a-user-from-resizing-the-column-width-of-a-clistctrl-report) 
LVCFMT_FIXED_WIDTH
This format style works, but only after the first column. The first column items is always moveable. Why? Do I have missing something?

```
for(int i = 0; i<NUM_COLUMNS; i++)
{
    m_ListCtrl.InsertColumn(i,_gszColumnLabel[i], _gnColumnFmt[i] |  LVCFMT_FIXED_WIDTH, _gnColumnWidth[i], -1);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first column [is special](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774743(VS.85).aspx) for some reason:

> If a column is added to a list-view control with index 0 (the leftmost column), it is always LVCFMT_LEFT. Setting other flags on column 0 does not override that alignment. Therefore if you keep inserting columns with index 0, the text in all columns are left-aligned. If you want the first column to be right-aligned or centered you can make a dummy column, then insert one or more columns with index 1 or higher and specify the alignment you require. Finally delete the dummy column.

Perhaps the dummy column trick will work in your case as well?

Answer (score 2):

A problem with LVCFMT_FIXED_WIDTH is that it is not possible to change the column width programmatically either (using SetColumnWidth). If you want to set the column width after the header control construction (for example in OnSize) you have to temporarily remove the LVCFMT_FIXED_WIDTH flag.

Here is an implementation that both has a workaround for not being able to modify the first column and one for not being able to programmatically modify a column with LVCFMT_FIXED_WIDTH:

```
void
MyTreeeCtrl::SetFixedColumnWidth(int col, int width)
{
  int colToModify = col;
  // Workaround 1: Insert a dummy column to be able to modify the attributes
  // of the first column.
  if (col == 0)
  {
    InsertColumn(0, L"");
    ++colToModify;
  }

  // Workaround 2: Temporarily remove the fixed width attribute to be able to
  // modify the width.
  LVCOLUMN colInfo;
  colInfo.mask = LVCF_FMT;
  GetColumn(colToModify, &colInfo);
  colInfo.fmt = colInfo.fmt & ~LVCFMT_FIXED_WIDTH;
  SetColumn(colToModify, &colInfo);

  // Set the column width
  SetColumnWidth(colToModify, width);

  // Restore the fixed width attribute
  colInfo.fmt = colInfo.fmt | LVCFMT_FIXED_WIDTH;
  SetColumn(colToModify, &colInfo);

  // Remove the dummy column
  if (col == 0)
  {
    DeleteColumn(0);
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice. I do not need this, because I disable resizing only in the FullScreen Mode.